# Fast Refresh Not Working in React Native in Visual Studio Code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator, watchman, fast-refresh

At some point, I believe when the project was update to RN 0.63.2 fast refresh completely stopped working when running debug iOS from Visual Studio Code.

- Fast refresh does still work when running from Xcode. (However then I loose the ability to set breakpoints in VSC)
- Strangely + thankfully the other devs on the project haven’t experienced this issue.

I believe I’ve tried every suggestion mentioned on the internet including:

- Reinstalling watchman
- Cleaning the watchman cache
- Cleaning the yarn cache
- Nuking node modules and pods (20X)
- Restarting computer (5X)
- Cold showers
- Nuking and re-cloning the entire repo.
- rm -rf .git/index.lock
- Reinstalling React Native Tools in VSC
- Making sure VSC is the latest.
- Toggling debug on/off in the sim action sheet menu
- Toggling Fast Refresh on/off in the sim action sheet menu
- Updating the sim
- Erasing + reinstalling on the sim

I’m currently having to completely close VSC (+ the metro bundler) and rebuild every time I make a change.  Ug.

Comment: Hi Alistair, did you manage to fix this problem? I'm currently facing it, it's quite annoying :(

Comment: Nope. At the moment I'm stuck using Xcode with React Native Debugger attached. (you can set breakpoints...but it's a lot more tedious launching the 3 apps + sim to work. ug).

Comment: I have same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Sorry nope. My current best hope it waiting until I'm eligible for a new MBP from my company.  React-Native-Life.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I found this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28420   ... the `sudo npx react-native start` solution worked for me.

Comment: Did you try hot showers

Comment: In all seriousness, I'm experiencing the same issue atm and came here before trying the nuclear option of recloning the entire project

Comment: Same bug, still no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue and went through many of the same possible answers with no luck.

I was curious as to why many people found that clearing the git index.lock worked. I did not have such a file so clearing it was not an option - however I then got to wondering if the issue is related to git permissions and the storage of credentials. I use a number of repositories across different projects and these include GitHub, BitBucket and AWS with the credentials helper for AWS being a bit of a pain.  The project I was experiencing issue with was on BitBucket and in vsCode I was being prompted for credentials on PULL etc but thought nothing of it.

I eventually switched to using the git local disk credential store to get round that (not recommended) and then discovered that watchman/RN Tools was working again!

So that is the good news and may help some.  I have however recently restarted my machine and find I am back in the same painful position.

So this is not the whole answer but does suggest there is a linkup between the issue and GIT - never been able to establish why!

I live for the answer as productivity is significantly impacted by having to restart metro and the debugger every time I make a change.